# Problems with Pican2 sending messages

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, can-bus

I've been experimenting with Pican2 and the python-can libraries and I've been able to read the bus and interpret many messages in my car. The problem is when I send a message to the bus (for example, turn on A/C), it quickly appears once in the candump printout and then reverts to its previous state. For example:

```
[436] 00 08 00 10 FE 00 00 01

[436] 04 10 00 10 FE 00 00 01

[436] 00 08 00 10 FE 00 00 01

[436] 00 08 00 10 FE 00 00 01

 ...
```

04 10 occur when A/C is on and fan speed is at level 1. I am sending this data... 00 08 is A/C is off, this overrides my can message on its own.

It seems as though I have to send the message in a loop for it to take. Is there something I am missing? I feel like I should just be able to send the message once and have the canbus accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Many functions controlled by CAN messages need periodic messages to keep them doing what they are doing. In your log, it looks like there are periodic messages controlling the fan.

Further reading: https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/threats/hacking-bus-basic-manipulation-modern-automobile-through-bus-reverse-engineering-37825